# lazily initialize a bean which is referenced by another lazy-init bean

Tags: java, spring, lazy-initialization

I have a bean which is lazily-initialized and have a couple of arguments and properties to be set.

```
  <bean id="abc" class="a.b.c.abc" lazy-init="true">
        <constructor-arg ref="qwert" />
        <property name="aImplementations">
            <list>
                <ref bean="newBean" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Whereas `newBean` is defined as `<bean id="newBean" class="a.b.c.newBean" lazy-init="true" init-method="init" />`

But lazy bean gets initialized and init() method is called.

If I remove bean `'abc'` and just keep `newBean`, init() method of newBean class is not called.

What could be the reason? I searched on Google but no help.

Comment: From your XML sample it looks like `abc` is **not** lazily initialized, which will cause observed problem. Is it a mistake in your example?

Comment: So, is `abc` referenced by any other, non-lazy bean?

Comment: No, doesn't look like. I just grepped in workspace and din't find anything.

Comment: You might put breakpoint in the constructor of `abc`. It's not easy, but with a little bit of practice you'll find out why Spring is loading that particular bean.

Answer (score 0):

a bean will only be lazy- initialized if it not has been referenced from any other bean or if it has referenced from another lazy initialized bean. Your bean 'abc' is non-lazy and while constructing this bean, it has to insert newBean into abc.

Comment: Try making your 'abc' bean lazy, then you will see init of your newbean will not be called at the application startup

Comment: Sorry, that is lazily initialized as the question states. I just missed to add here. Added! :)

Comment: then check for it's reference in some bean which is non-lazy